# Problema Primary Key(ID) Sequelize

Tags: mysql, nodejs, typescript, express, sequelize

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente inconveniente:
Estoy haciendo un backend  con NodeJs , express, sequelize y Typescript , el problema que tengo es en el UPDATE(PUT) , que es el controlador para actualizar información donde si manipulo el ID desde Postman este lo cambia sin problemas.

Esta es mi tabla :

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| product_id    | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_name  | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| createdAt     | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updatedAt     | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| userId        | int         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| subcategoryId | int         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

este es mi Model:

```
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

export const ProductModel = (sequelize: any) => {
  const Product = sequelize.define('product', {
    product_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: 'productIdUnique'

    },
    product_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'table_product',
    timestamps: true
  })

  return Product;
}
```

Y este mi controlador

```
export const updateProduct = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: errors.array()
    })
  }

  const id = req.params.id

  try {
    let products = await Product.update(req.body, {
      where: { product_id: id }
    })

    products = await Product.findByPk(req.params.id);

    if (!products) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        ok: false,
        message: 'Product'
      })
    } else {
      return res.status(200).json({
        ok: true,
        message: 'Product Update',
        products
      })
    }

  } catch (error: any) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      ok: false,
      message: 'Error Updating Product',
      error
    })
  }

}
```

Hasta donde tengo entendido las PK o ID no tienen porque modificarse en un backend, ya que es una práctica poco recomendada,

Cuando hago el PUT desde Postman :

```
{
    "product_id":5,
    "product_name":"New Product 1212342"
}
```

Como explique anteriormente se modifica sin ningún tipo de restricción.
En todo caso quiero saber si hay una manera de evitar este tipo de comportamiento.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Haz el [tour] para conocer el functionamiento del sitio (y de paso obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)). ¿Podrías editar la pregunta indicando la estructura de tu tabla?

Comment: Si, lo acabo de editar para que se entienda mejor